# Error de NullPointer en la última SDK de Mercado Pago

Tags: java, android, mercadopago, excepciones, nullpointerexception

Estoy trabjando con la última versión de la SDK de Mercado Pago para Android, la 3.2.0, y con el código de la última documentación.

El error se produce en tiempo de ejecución (*runtime*) cuando se ejecuta el `submit` del activity, luego de completar todos los datos que se piden (número de tarjeta, apellido, nombre, fecha expiración, código, documento), o sea que puedo cargar todos los datos de pago pero explota antes de devolver el *callback*.

Por lo que pude debuguear, lo hace cuando quiere obtener el token de la tarjeta, pero no tengo claro si es que el token que crea la SDK es nulo o uno de las 3 variables `Date` internas, lo que estoy seguro es que es un error de la versión actual.

En un fragment tengo este código de llamada a la activity de MercadoPago:

```
List<Item> items = createItems();
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
CheckoutPreference checkoutPreference = new CheckoutPreference.Builder()
    .addItems(items)
    .setSite(Sites.ARGENTINA)
    .addExcludedPaymentType(PaymentTypes.TICKET) //Handle exclusions by payment types
    //.addExcludedPaymentMethod(PaymentMethods.ARGENTINA.VISA) //Exclude specific payment methods
    //.setMaxInstallments(1) //Limit the amount of installments
    .setExpirationDate(gc.getTime())
    .setActiveFrom(new Date())
    .setPayerEmail("xxxx")
    .enableAccountMoney()
    .build();
startMercadoPagoCheckout(checkoutPreference);



private void startMercadoPagoCheckout(CheckoutPreference checkoutPreference) {
        new MercadoPagoCheckout.Builder()
            .setActivity(getActivity())
            .setPublicKey("TEST-24db192f-ebce-4270-8108-b8faa753e9be")
            .setCheckoutPreference(checkoutPreference)
            .startForPaymentData();
    }
```

A continuación les paso el stack trace:

```
08-08 09:17:42.478 29816-29816/xxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: , PID: 29816 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
  at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1195) 
  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:518)
  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:820)
  at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:314)
  at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.write(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:88)
  at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.write(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:40)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:669)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:583)
  at com.mercadopago.util.JsonUtil.toJson(JsonUtil.java:32)
  at com.mercadopago.GuessingCardActivity.finishCardFlow(GuessingCardActivity.java:1555)
  at com.mercadopago.presenters.GuessingCardPresenter.resolvePayerCosts(GuessingCardPresenter.java:1096)
  at com.mercadopago.presenters.GuessingCardPresenter.access$2300(GuessingCardPresenter.java:48)
  at com.mercadopago.presenters.GuessingCardPresenter$9.success(GuessingCardPresenter.java:1066)
  at com.mercadopago.presenters.GuessingCardPresenter$9.success(GuessingCardPresenter.java:1059)
  at com.mercadopago.adapters.ErrorHandlingCallAdapter$MPCallAdapter$1$1.run(ErrorHandlingCallAdapter.java:90)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 08-08 09:17:42.482 1063-1462/? W/ActivityManager: Force finishing activity 1 xxx/com.mercadopago.GuessingCardActivity
```

Comment: En el código compartido sólo hay una línea en la que hay un `getTime` y es en una variable que instancias al principio (`gc`) y que no viene de Mercado Pago. ¿Seguro que esto es un error de Mercado Pago y no algo que no funciona bien en el código (p.e. que la variable no se esté instanciando bien o una operación que haga esa variable null)?

Comment: hola @AlvaroMontoro, gracias por tu comentario, esa variable no es el problema esta bien instanciada y la tuve que agregar para que no tire el mismo error el sdk cuando se instancia el Activity, como comenté en la pregunta, el error ocurre cuando el sdk quiere parciar un objeto Token propio del sdk, osea que es un problema interno, gracias.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema que vos y uso última versión de la SDK

Comment: Por lo que estuve investigando el problema esta en una request, para crear el Token, el sdk hace una peticion a una request que no he podido encontrar y aparentemente eso fallaria.

Answer (score 0):

El código del sdk está en [GitHub](https://github.com/mercadopago/px-android).

La función en el Activity es:

```
@Override
    public void finishCardFlow(PaymentMethod paymentMethod, Token token, Discount discount, Boolean directDiscountEnabled, Issuer issuer, List<PayerCost> payerCosts) {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("paymentMethod", JsonUtil.getInstance().toJson(paymentMethod));
        returnIntent.putExtra("token", JsonUtil.getInstance().toJson(token)); //1555
        returnIntent.putExtra("issuer", JsonUtil.getInstance().toJson(issuer));
        returnIntent.putExtra("payerCosts", JsonUtil.getInstance().toJson(payerCosts));
        returnIntent.putExtra("discount", JsonUtil.getInstance().toJson(discount));
        returnIntent.putExtra("directDiscountEnabled", directDiscountEnabled);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mpsdk_slide_right_to_left_in, R.anim.mpsdk_slide_right_to_left_out);
}
```

La línea donde comienza el problema sería esta:

```
returnIntent.putExtra("token", JsonUtil.getInstance().toJson(token));
```

`JsonUtil.toJson()` solamente hace

```
 return mGson.toJson(src);
```

Ya después las llamadas son de Gson.

El parametro que está tratando de convertir parece ser el token. Fijate si lo ves bien formateado al token que estás pasando.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si esa es la linea de codigo, te comento que no le estoy pasando ningun token, en la documentacion no habla de pasarle ninguno, supuse que eso era interno, el problema es la documentacion que no explica que pasar y que no, no se que pasarle en este caso

Comment: el token lo obtiene con una request al api de mercado pago